# ImageView inflating error

Tags: android, android-imageview

I get this issue when I try to start my app. I refer some blogs but not getting proper solution.
I am trying to run app in Android Version 4.1.1 but
Facing this error.
It is completely ok in higher version like 5.0.0 and below

here is error:

(may be this error occur because of  **ic_cancel** drawable resource and it is vector drawable)

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fontchanger.pixsterstudio/com.fontchanger.pixsterstudio.Activity.DashBoard}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #178: Error inflating class ImageView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is my layout code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Activity.DashBoard">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/blurrel">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_new"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/blink"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/scrollEdt"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <com.fontchanger.pixsterstudio.Custome.CustomRegularEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edtType"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:background="@drawable/ractangle_line"
            android:lines="5"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:hint="Type hear..."
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="9"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edtType">
            <com.fontchanger.pixsterstudio.Custome.CustomSemiBoldTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtNew"
                android:text="New"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"/>

            <com.fontchanger.pixsterstudio.Custome.CustomSemiBoldTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtCopy"
                android:text="Copy"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"/>
            <com.fontchanger.pixsterstudio.Custome.CustomSemiBoldTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtSave"
                android:text="Save"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linTemp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linerNavigation"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/green1"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:transitionName="simple_activity_transition"
            tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/imgList"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:src="@drawable/list"
                android:layout_weight="2"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/imgEdit"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:src="@drawable/pencile"
                android:layout_weight="2"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/imgEmoji"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:src="@drawable/emoji"
                android:layout_weight="2"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:id="@+id/imgHistory"
                android:src="@drawable/history"
                android:layout_weight="2"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/imgShare"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:src="@drawable/share"
                android:layout_weight="2"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:id="@+id/lvFont"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/lvSaveList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
        <com.fontchanger.pixsterstudio.Custome.CustomRegularTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNoData"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Recent list is empty."
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relTransparent"
        android:background="#cc000000"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/imgCancel"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgCancel"
            android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
            <com.fontchanger.pixsterstudio.Custome.CustomSemiBoldTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Backspace is not working smoothly in this font."
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>
            <com.fontchanger.pixsterstudio.Custome.CustomRegularTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="This is mostly due to lack of unicode support in this android version, this issue might be solved automatically in future version of android."
                android:textColor="#AEB6BF"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"/>
            <com.fontchanger.pixsterstudio.Custome.CustomSemiBoldTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="But there are few workaround which can help : "
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>
            <com.fontchanger.pixsterstudio.Custome.CustomRegularTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="• Either select individual letter which you want to erase"
                android:textColor="#AEB6BF"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"/>
            <com.fontchanger.pixsterstudio.Custome.CustomRegularTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="• If you want to remove everything you have to select new"
                android:textColor="#AEB6BF"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"/>
            <com.fontchanger.pixsterstudio.Custome.CustomRegularTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="• Combine working font with non-working one, and erase non working fonts as well"
                android:textColor="#AEB6BF"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"/>
            <com.fontchanger.pixsterstudio.Custome.CustomRegularTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="• Some non-working fonts can be erased by holding the erase button from the keypad continuously"
                android:textColor="#AEB6BF"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"/>
            <com.fontchanger.pixsterstudio.Custome.CustomSemiBoldTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Important Notes : "
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"/>
            <com.fontchanger.pixsterstudio.Custome.CustomRegularTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="If you use working font with non working font, it may happen that the whole appearance changes."
                android:textColor="#AEB6BF"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If there any solution please share.
        Thank you

Comment: Post your layout xml above. The error says "file line #178: Error inflating class ImageView". That is relevant. Check it.

Comment: share your xml file.

Comment: share your code

Comment: how can we use vector drawable file in os 4?

Answer (score -1):

Check your Id of the Imageview is same as the id you are getting from findviewbyid or from BindView and the id should be in the same layout which you are inflating. 
Paste the code if more problem.

Comment: It will case when you will not have proper id call after inflating as well.

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #178: Error inflating class ImageView 
Check this man its error inflating imageView not Linearlout.

Comment: Let him check I had same error just I change checked id and it worked. If it works then its fine for him.

Comment: id is proper but I guess I am using vector drawable file as image resource so it may be not supported in os 4

Comment: it is attached with this question but I found the solution thanks for your response